# Why do we use port number localhost: 8080? Why don't we use a port number when using www.example.com?

Tags: java, web-applications, cloud-foundry

When I use a Spring Boot app in local it uses, `localhost:8080`. When it is pushed to Pivotal Cloud Foundry, it has some route `https://my-app.xyz-domain.com` and we can access the URL without a port, what is happening behind the scene?

Please help me understand.

Comment: "what is happening behind the scene" it's implicitly using port 443. See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CloudFoundry, your application is actually still running on `localhost:8080`. The reason that you can access your application through https://my-app.xyz-domain.com is that the platform handles routing the traffic from that URL to your application.

---

The way this works is as follows:

1. You deploy your application. It's run by the foundation in a container. The container is assigned a port, which it provides to the application through the `$PORT` env variable (this can technically change, but it's been 8080 for a long time). Your application then listens on `localhost:$PORT` or effectively `localhost:8080`.
2. The platform also runs Envoy in your container. It's configured to listen for incoming HTTP and HTTPS requests, and it will proxy that traffic to your application on `localhost:$PORT`.
3. Using the `cf` cli, you map a route to your application. This is a logical rule that tells the platform what external traffic should go to your application. A route can consist of a hostname, domain, and/or path. For example, `my-cool-app.example.com` or `my-cool-app.example.com/foo`. For a route to work, the domain must have its DNS directed to the platform.
4. When an end-user accesses the route that you mapped, the DNS resolves to the platform and the traffic is directed to the external load balancers (sometimes TCP/layer4, sometimes HTTPS/layer7) that sit in front of the platform. These proxies do not have knowledge of CF, they just proxy incoming traffic.
5. Traffic from the external load balancers is spread across the set of the platform Gorouters. The Gorouter is a second layer of proxies, but these proxies have knowledge of the platform, specifically, all of the routes that have been mapped on the platform and where those applications actually live.

   When a request comes to Gorouter, it will recognize the route like `my-cool-app.example.com` and look up the location of the container where that app is running. Traffic from Gorouter is then proxied to the Envoy which is running in the app container. This ties into step two as the Envoy will route that traffic to your application.

All in total, incoming requests are routed like this:

```
Client/Browser -> External LBs -> Gorouters -> Envoy -> Application
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the detailed answer, really appreciate it.
I have a question. If a microservice happens to register itself with a discovery client (e.g Eureka server) with an application name, then is it going to register with the route such as "https://myapp.example.com" or with something else ?

Comment: That is up to you. You can register with the route and traffic to your microservice will go through all the layers I described above. This can be helpful in that it provides load balancing at the cost of some overhead/latency to go through the additional hops. Instead, you could register the local IP and use the container-to-container network for your traffic. This can reduce latency but you need to do client-side loadbalancing because you're talking directly from one app instance to another. Obviously, you can only do c2c if you're in the same foundation.

Answer (score 3):

There is a default port number for each protocol which is used by the browser if none is specified. For https it is 443, for http 80 and for telnet 23.

On Unix and similar systems like Linux, those are often not available to a developer so other ports are used but then they have to be specified. 8080 is often available and looks like 80.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change the port to 80 or 443, because HTTP corresponds to 80, and HTTPS corresponds to 443. Then, you should set the domain name to resolve to the current host, so that you can access the current application through the domain name. In addition, if you want to set the local domain name, then The hosts file should be modified.

Comment: Also on Unixes only root can open ports < 1024

Comment: you're right ,i get it,thanks